# The video takes a while to disappear when navigating

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have one screen running video and when I switch to the next screen, the compositables appear and the video still takes a while to disappear. Can anyone explain what's going on?

This is the screen's code to play the video and the ClickableLoginComponent will navigate when pressed:

```
Box(.....) {
        .....

         Column(..){
        ButtonClick(text = "Login", isEnabled = loginViewModel.allValidationPass.value,
            onClick = {
             
                vm.login(email =loginViewModel.loginUIState.value.email , password =loginViewModel.loginUIState.value.password )
                navController.navigate(Screen.HomeScreen.route)
            })
        DividerTextComponent()

        ClickableLoginComponent(tryingToLogin = false,text="Register",onTextSelected={
            navController.navigate(Screen.SignUpScreen.route)
        })
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
    }
    if(loginViewModel.loginInProgress.value){
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }

}
```

Here is the code to get the video:

```
val videoUri: Uri = 

    Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.appmusic/raw/tunnel")
    
    fun VideoPlay(
        videoUri:Uri,modifier: Modifier=Modifier
    ){
        AndroidView(modifier=modifier,
            factory ={context->VideoView(context)
                            .apply{
                            setVideoURI(videoUri)
                            setOnPreparedListener{ start()
                                it.isLooping = true}
                            }
            }
                    )
    }
```